# How to pass variables from view to controller methods in spring

Tags: spring, logging, aop

I am trying to log run time data in spring using AOP. I am able to log the static messages. But my problem is I have to log the input values given by the user(Eg.Name) and my log message should be as" Siva has logged in" if the user enters 'siva' as username in the form.

I have a jsp form with text boxes for getting username , bean class which has setter and getter for the username, a controller class and an aspect class.

My controller class is:

```
@RequestMapping("/login.htm")

public ModelAndView success(String name){

}
```

My Aspect class is:

```
   @After("execution(* com.controller.MyController.success(String))&&args(name)")

public void After(){

    System.out.println("after method");
}
```

I am not sure how to get the username in the controller method. I am totally blind. I searched and tried many possibilities but nothing worked out. Any help is appreciated....Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the username parameter in your controller method you just need to annotate the "name" argument with @RequestParam. e.g.:

```
@RequestMapping("/login.htm")

public ModelAndView success(@RequestParam("name") String name){

}
```

And to get the name in your after advice, just change the after method's signature to accept "name" string:

```
@After("execution(* com.controller.MyController.success(String))&&args(name)")

public void after(String name){
    logger.info("User "+name+" has logged in!");
}
```

Hope it solves the issues.

Comment: @PavithraR could you please upvote the answer and mark it as resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
//your Aspect class
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.controller.MyController.success(..)) && args(username)")
    public void controllerExecution(String username){};

    @After("controllerExecution(username)")
    public void afterControllerExecution(final String username){
         System.out.println("username is : " + username);
    }
}

//the method in your controller
@RequestMapping(value="/success")
public String success(String username){
    return "home";
}
```

The request url would be something like this : www.XXX.com/success?username=Johnny
@Piyush Joshi, in this case, you **don't necessarily** have to use @RequestParam to get AOP works.